# wp_ajax action is not run when ajax trigger

Tags: ajax, actions

I'm trying to implement the ajax in wordpress world but now stuck.
Function hook suppose to be called when ajax triggered is not happening.

I check the network

- admin-ajax.php is called but response is null implied that    getsomething function is not called.

Anyone have any idea?

Follow are my code.

functions.php

```
function my_resource() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'/jqfunctions.js');
    wp_localize_script( 'my-jquery', 'myback', 
    array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_resource');
```

jqfunctions.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#popular").click(function(){
    console.log('popular clicked');
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: myback.ajax_url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{
            action: 'getsomething'
        },
        success: function( response ){
            console.log("This is response...");
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function( error ){
            console.log('AJAX error callback....');
            console.log(error);
        }
       });
    });
});
```

admin-ajax.php

```
 function getsomething(){
 wp_send_json_error('hey');
 }


 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getsomething', 'getsomething');
 add_action('wp_ajax_getsomething', 'getsomething');
```

Comment: "Admin-ajax.php" is the Name of the wordpress file that handles Ajax requests, not a file you have to create. Put Your "admin-ajax.php" code into the functions.php and it should be working!

Comment: Follow right sequence for localizing. 1. Register 2. Localize  3. Enqueue

Comment: It's working like u suggested @kuchenundkakao ,shifting  my code from admin-ajax.php to functions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code and it works perfectly. I've just declared the dependencies for the JavaScript, so it is loaded correctly after jQuery. This is how I've tested it:

**functions.php**

```
function my_resource() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'/jqfunctions.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script( 'my-jquery', 'myback', 
    array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_resource');
function getsomething(){
  wp_send_json_error('hey');
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getsomething', 'getsomething');
add_action('wp_ajax_getsomething', 'getsomething');
```

**jqfunctions.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#popular").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('popular clicked');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: myback.ajax_url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{
            action: 'getsomething'
        },
        success: function( response ){
            console.log("This is response...");
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function( error ){
            console.log('AJAX error callback....');
            console.log(error);
        }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for testing my code. now it 's working by moving that chuck of code from admin-ajax.php to functions.php

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved the problem, to close the question. We should avoid modifying core files, like `admin-ajax.php` @PondPisutaarnon